# How to get nearest previous input checkbox with name "checkthis" using queryselector on an element?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api, queryselector

```
<input name="checkthis" type="checkbox">
<span>text here</span>
<input type="text" name="checkthis">
<input type="text" name="another">
<input type="text">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text" id="eventTarget" oninput="findPreviousInputcheckboxCheckthis">
```

How to get previous input checkbox with name "checkthis" using queryselector on an element?

```
function findPreviousInputcheckboxCheckthis(ev) {
  checkboxCheckthis = ev.target.querySelector( "input[name='checkthis']);
}
```

Edit: There are many more input checkboxes with `name="checkthis"` before and after the snippet I posted. They are nested in other element also.
I simply want the nearest previous checkbox in the html-source starting from the target, nested or not.

Comment: Is it ev.target.closest(css-selector)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your below comment, I have updated the answer snippet where you need to add parent div structure and then you can find the checkthis name attribute quickly. Please check below working snippet:

```js
function findPreviousInputcheckbdfoxCheckthis(ev) {

  var selectElement = document.getElementById(ev);
  selectElement.querySelector('input[name="checkthis"]').style.visibility = "hidden";
  
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">

<input name="checkthis" type="checkbox" value="previous"> 
<span>text here</span>
<input type="text" name="checkthis"> 
<input type="text" name="another">
<input type="text">
<input type="checkbox" value="next">
<input type="text" id="eventTarget" oninput="findPreviousInputcheckbdfoxCheckthis(this.parentElement.id)" placeholder="Previous checkbox">

</div>
```

Here, I have added div1 id and you can repeat the same by using using ID and rest the JavaScript will be same and it will find your first previous "name=checkthis" checkbox.

Hope this solution will be work for you!

**Also, below is the link where I have used multiple repeat structure. Please refer it also:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/3d8g49nm/96/

Comment: There are many more input checkboxes with name="checkthis" before and after the snippet I posted. They are nested in other element also. I simply want the nearest previous checkbox in the html-source starting from the target, nested or not.

Comment: Shared full html

Comment: Pattern is going to be same: <input name="checkthis" type="checkbox" value="previous"> 
<span>text here</span>
<input type="text" name="checkthis"> ?

Comment: I have updated the answer snippet. Please check it again.

Comment: After assessing the situation anew, the only way to loop upward siblings, parentelement, parentelement structures downwards, upwards parentelement sibling, and so on. I finally came up with the same solution you suggest, because I have full control over the html-structure. It's not really an answer to my original question, but it works. Thank you!